# How to use Velocity template inside java class

Tags: java, velocity, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to use a velocity template inside java class below is my code

```
 VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
 ve.init();
 VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();       
 context.put("object", someobject);
 Template t = ve.getTemplate("template.vm");
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 t.merge(context, writer);
```

The code throws resource not found at the line

> ve.getTemplate("template.vm")

regardless of how i give the path it is not taking.

what should be my path for that template.vm

it is not inside the web-inf folder but inside the web directory.

I found the problem to be the properties not being set properly

```
Properties velocityProperties = new Properties();
velocityProperties.put("resource.loader", "class");
velocityProperties.put("class.resource.loader.description", "Velocity Classpath Resource Loader");
velocityProperties.put("class.resource.loader.class",
                "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
            velocityProperties.put("file.resource.loader.class","org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader");
velocityProperties.put("file.resource.loader.path","/");
velocityProperties.put("file.resource.loader.cache","false");

ve.init(velocityProperties
```

once i put this it is picking up my template.

);

Comment: Could you try to put ur templates under WEB-INF/classes folder (base source folder in your java project)

Comment: I tried putting it there but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: If you have a file on the path WEB-INF/classes/template.vm in your build dist, it should be loading it.

Comment: updating my question. PLease check . also suggest how to change the path to point outside the web-inf folder? Thanks

Comment: your template is being found when it is under WEB-INF classes,  right?

Comment: yes. it is found in web-inf/classes

Answer (score 0):

In your app conf xml you must specify the bean and where template are located, also the extension of templates. In my case:

```
<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
</bean>

<!-- View resolvers can also be configured with ResourceBundles or XML files.
    If you need different view resolving based on Locale, you have to use the
    resource bundle resolver. -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
    <property name="toolboxConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/velocity-toolbox.xml" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I do not use Spring. how do i set the properties for velocity?

Comment: your properties are set in a good way. I think that velocityProperties.put("file.resource.loader.path","/"); is the problem. What refer "/"? Had you try to get a real context path?

In my case with speing i do:
        WebApplicationContext context = (WebApplicationContext) ApplicationContextProvider.provide();
        String path = context.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/");
You must get a real path "/" is for you?

Comment: i figured it out. after i give it the path, icould access the rest of the templeates outside of web-inf by doing /../../folder1/template2.vm